# Android Wear: WearableActivity with FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, wear-os

When using the WearableActivity you can't reach `getSupportFragmentManager()` which `FragmentPagerAdapter` requires, so you need to use `getFragmentManager()`.

#### Activity

```
public MyWearActivity extends WearableActivity {

    public ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments;
    public ArrayList<String> mTitles;
    public ViewPager mViewPager;
    public PageFragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        mTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

```
        mPagerAdapter = new PageFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()); <-- PROBLEM
```

```
        // More code
    }
}
```

#### Pager adapter

```
public class PageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
```

```
        super(fm); <-- PROBLEM
```

```
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PageFragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

What can I do to use a `FragmentPagerAdapter` inside a `WearableActivity`?

Answer (score 5):

Just came across the same problem.

I've got around it with adding

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1+'
```

to the dependencies in the build.gradle file. Then where you use the FragmentPagerAdapter add

```
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

Not sure if there's a better way yet.