# Android wear drag next view horizontal

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have an Android Wear app with 2 activities. The first activity is my Main Activity, and the second activity is my OptionActivity. What I have done so far is to use OnFling to show the second activity when a user swipes from right to left. But instead I want drag my next activity , so I can see what is there is on the next view.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if (event1.getX() - event2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"OnRightToLeft Fling",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OptionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (event2.getX() - event1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"OnLeftToRight Fling",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (event1.getY() - event2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onBottomToTop Fling",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (event2.getY() - event1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"OnTopToBottom Fling",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Anyone who can explain me how this is done on an Android wear?

Comment: You are probably looking for ViewPager - you do it exactly in the same manner as in case of mobile apps.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try to implement a ViewPager.

Comment: Do you have an example, of how it works on Android Wear?

Answer (score 1):

In relation to @pablo432's comment, here's a [sample code](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/ca2d0a9f79b902b19a65) on how to use a simple a `GridViewPager` with a `FragmentGridPagerAdapter`.

```
public class GridActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid);

        final GridViewPager mGridPager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mGridPager.setAdapter(new SampleGridPagerAdapter(this, getFragmentManager()));
    }
}
```

Additional references:

- [Android Wear: WearableActivity with FragmentPagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100157/android-wear-wearableactivity-with-fragmentpageradapter)
- [What is the correct way to implement a GridViewPager on Android Wear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788423/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-gridviewpager-on-android-wear)

Comment: According to official documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridViewPager.html), GridViewPager is deprecated. It is recommended to use "regular" ViewPager class instead and do it just like on mobile apps (Google and Stack Overflow are full of this kind of examples).